# rails destroy scaffold leaves back table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, schema, scaffold

I created a new scaffold using the command:

```
rails generate scaffold level
```

But then I destroyed it using the command

```
rails destroy scaffold level
```

And then again added it back using the command

```
rails generate scaffold level question:string answer:string prev_q:integer next_q:integer
```

But now when I try rake db:migrate then I get the following error

```
 SQLite3::SQLException: table "levels" already exists: CREATE TABLE "levels" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "question" varchar(255), "answer" varchar(255), "prev_q" integer, "next_q" integer, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
```

My migrate/create_level.rb is

```
class CreateLevels < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :levels do |t|
  t.string :question
  t.string :answer
  t.integer :prev_q
  t.integer :next_q

  t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

But my schema.rb is:

```
  create_table "levels", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

I want to know that how can I update the levels table in the schema. Also I would like to know that why doesn't the table get deleted when I destroy the scaffold. Do I need to run another command to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I had to do was:

First I followed the steps specified by @Alex Siri.

But after doing that using

```
rake db:migrate
```

Did not add the values question,answer etc to the table, so I did the following steps

1. I again deleted the scaffold using the command

   `rails destroy scaffold level`
2. After that I again created the scaffold using the command:

   `rails generate scaffold level question:string answer:string prev_q:integer next_q:integer`
3. Finally I ran migration using

   `rake db:migrate`

This solved my problem. I wrote all the steps so that if anyone else has the same problem then they can easily solve it.

Answer (score 11):

Using `destroy scaffold` does not run the rollback to the migration. The correct way of doing it would have been

```
rake db:rollback
rails destroy scaffold level
```

now, as you don't have that other migration anymore, you cannot roll it back. You'll need to delete that table manually:

```
rails dbconsole
DROP TABLE levels;
```

Comment: So after dropping the table should I manually add everything in the table or just run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: just run `rake db:migrate`